# Access IdentityUser from Blazor Client

Tags: blazor, asp.net-core-identity

I'm currently using Blazor WebAssembly, ASP.NET Core hosted, EF/Identity Core.

I want to fill a dropdown of *countries* and another one of *users* in my client side Blazor page.

`Country` is easy because its model is in `\Shared\Models\Country.cs`.

I'm struggling to bring `UserIdentity` because it is part of Microsoft Identity and I can't put in my `\Shared\Models`. So, the compiler doesn't recognize the entity and I can't bring its namespace.

Any ideas of how can I populate the user's dropdown?
Maybe creating a dummy class called `\Shared\Models\AppUser.cs` that inherits from `UserIdentity` is enough?

Or maybe add reference to the Server project?

This is the sample code:

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorApp.Shared.Models
@inject HttpClient Http

<h1>Dropdown Example</h1>

@if (countryList == null || userList == null )
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="">-- Select Country --</option>
    @foreach (var country in countryList)
    {
        <option value="@country.Id">@country.CountryName</option>
    }
</select>

<select class="form-control">
    <option value="">-- Select User --</option>
    @if (userList != null)
    {
        @foreach (var user in userList)
        {
            <option value="@user.Id">@user.UserName</option>
        }
    }
</select>
}

@functions {
    List<Country> countryList = new List<Country>();
    List<IdentityUser> userList = new List<IdentityUser>();

    protected override async Task OnInitAsync() {
        countryList = await Http.GetJsonAsync<List<Country>>("api/country/GetCountryList");
        userList = await Http.GetJsonAsync<List<IdentityUser>>("api/user/GetUserList");
    }
}
```

Comment: possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58661485/blazor-and-identity

Comment: Identity is a server-side affair. You can't use it (directly) in the browser. Create a DTO.